# Application trying to call a local library .dll that is no more appearing in the references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, .net-core

I created a custom library named it `portableLibrary` and added it to my C# soluation `using portableLibrary;`
after a time I changed its name to be `UtilityMethods`, so I removed the old one from my solution, and added the new one. 
Everytime I try to debug or execute the application, since that time, the system showing me this error, tha indicate it is trying o call the old name, which is not in the references any more!!

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'portableLibrary, Version=1.0.6146.37242, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

[image]

Comment: Check the name in the properties of that library. Changing a name usually is not a good idea. Also, do the obvious clean and rebuild. Restart VS. weirdly, it just works out at times

Comment: Have you tried Clean and Rebuild solution?

Comment: I tried ` clean all` and deleted the `bin` and `obj` and restarted bot Xamarin and VS, but none of these worked :(

Comment: Why don't you just re-create the Portable assembly and reference it in a new project? Double check your `.csproj` to ensure the reference is changed.

Comment: Don't know much about Xamarin, but I had similar issue in Visual Studio and closing it, deleting .suo file and opening it again helped.